# MVC3 .NET model is storing null instead of array of values on save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am sending a POST request to MVC application in IIS 7. The problem is that the model that is supposed to fetch post data is returning null **only** for `webClipImage` key.

Fact is that `webClipImage` array contains quite long string as they hold base64 encoded images. However ASP.NET does not raise any exception that it couldn't parse the request because it was too long or something, it just makes WHOLE `webClipImage[]` array null.

In the link below you can find post data (not pasting it here as it's long). Note that I removed very long strings by appending "...." end the end

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=U5Q3wZjB

This is IIS log line. 46725 is number of bytes received and content length registered in Chrome was 46201 so I can confirm that the request was complete.

```
2015-03-09 00:28:17 MIKEHOME ::1 POST /otaapp/SaveData/Config _dc=1425860897591 80 - ::1 <browser_info> localhost 500 0 0 10087 46725 7`
```

This is how model looks like (cut)

```
public class SaveModel
{
    public string PayloadDescription { get; set; }
    public string PayloadDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PayloadIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string PayloadOrganization { get; set; }
    public string PayloadRemovalDisallowed { get; set; }
    public string RemovalPassword { get; set; }

    public string[] webClipImage { get; set; }
    public string[] webClipImageIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string[] webClipType { get; set; }
    public string[] webClipLabel { get; set; }
    public string[] webClipUrl { get; set; }
    public int[] IsRemovable { get; set; }
    public int[] Precomposed { get; set; }
    public int[] FullScreen { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

And this is Save controller

```
public class SaveDataController : Common
{
    //
    // GET: /Save/Config
    // Creates cfg.mobileconfig file based on values get from Sencha app.
    public string Config(SaveModel model)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/javascript"; <--- BREAKPOINT
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can see the line where I set the breakpoint and this is `model` view from the debugger. As you can see `webClipImage` is null!

[image]

Comment: Make sure your webClipImage is spelled correctly on the client side.  The null can happen because the mapper couldn't find the corresponding element in the post data.

Comment: The webClipImage **is** spelled correctly  because sometimes it works (I didn't figure out when it doesn't, for now it's random). Check the pastebin, it is exactly the same. (ctrl+f)

Comment: Are you sure the encoding is correct and you are not trying to pass a terminating character in the string?

Comment: I'm not sure about encoding but it's all base64 encoded so only basic set of chars is used there anyway. Terminating char is %00? nope. In this pastebin you can see full request. As you can see all 4 images are actually same strings. Removing some of them can cause the query to succeed. http://pastebin.com/ijauiCwA

Comment: Those are not very long strings in the scheme of things. Well below the default limits. How are you crafting the query?

Comment: That's a bit more complex to be able to explain in few words. I'm creating them inside a Ext JS app. However I thought that what browser shows me is enough data to figure out the solution. Also, if it matters, it's a `XMLHttpRequest` query.

Comment: My guess is that is where the issue lies.

Comment: `Fiddler` is your friend.

Comment: I didn't think '%' is a valid character for base64. Your last pastbin seems to contain these characters, is that correct?

Comment: It's hex encoded URL, it's decoded on server side.